# Cough treatment with well-understood mechanism of action

Tags: common-cold, antibiotics, cough

The medicines for cough threatment can be attributed to several classes:

- antibiotics and antiviral drugs
- mucolytics
- antitussives
- expectorants
- bronchodilators

Are there any other means of cough treatment with a well-understood mechanism of action, except by these categories?

As a counter-example of treatments with unclear mechanism of action, there are syrups based on mixes of herbs with obscure functions. Or "folk remedies" such as chicken soup or raspberry tea.

Comment: The general idea you are asking about is very interesting, but I think that you would get better answers if you edited your question to narrow it down a bit, make it more precise. There are many types of medicines used for cough (not trying to answer in comment, but just to illustrate): antitussives, expectorants, bronchodilators (in some cases) etc. and each group contains sub-groups with different mechanisms. As for herbal syrups - depends on the herbs they contain. Chicken soup and raspberry tea are more of folk remedies for common cold, than for cough per se. The answer would be too long.

Comment: @Lucky thank you so much for naming those classes of medicines, that's partially what I wanted.